# JSON values from php page not showing

Tags: java, android, json

Although this is just a rough sketch..i just want to see if it will work..Anytime i run the program it doesn't crash and it doesn't show anything. The error showing on the logcat is JSON result form the php page..i don't know why the Postexecute() method is not working...

this is the error

> 09-14 18:21:07.079: E/JSON(21310):
>   {"tag":"getTopic","success":1,"error":0,"data":[{"title":"Facebook
>   finally rolls GRAPH Search","tid":"81","time":"2013-06-22
>   10:05:18"},{"title":"What is Ubuntu for
>   Android?","tid":"69","time":"2013-06-22 10:18:00"},{"title":"Android
>   and Windows on same device(samsung)","tid":"98","time":"2013-06-22
>   10:18:35"},{"title":"\"Tweet\" has been verified as a real word in
>   English","tid":"67","time":"2013-06-22 10:27:33"},{"title":"Instagram
>   now has video recording","tid":"97","time":"2013-06-22
>   10:27:45"},{"title":"An Open Letter to
>   DBanj","tid":"70","time":"2013-06-22 10:31:41"},{"title":"MTN call
>   rate wahala","tid":"84","time":"2013-06-22 10:32:44"},{"title":"Types
>   of friends essential for women","tid":"33","time":"2013-06-22
>   10:45:41"},{"title":"Not to be loved in
>   return","tid":"106","time":"2013-06-22 18:15:06"},{"title":"I am in
>   love with you","tid":"107","time":"2013-06-22 18:28:56"},{"title":"I
>   hate it!!!","tid":"115","time":"2013-06-23 19:06:26"},{"title":"Spoils
>   of love","tid":"116","time":"2013-06-23 19:14:43"},{"title":"An
>   Apology Letter from Men To Women","tid":"117","time":"2013-06-26
>   12:43:02"},{"title":"Ramadan Starts tomorrow (in sha Allah)
>   !!!","tid":"120","time":"2013-07-09 15:06:09"},{"title":"Preventing
>   infidelity on your marriage","tid":"29","time":"2013-07-14
>   12:06:31"},{"title":"How to have a healthy
>   relationship","tid":"121","time":"2013-08-02 17:17:32"},{"title":"ASUU
>   strike not ending anytime soon","tid":"124","time":"2013-08-27
>   12:56:26"},{"title":"Google Announces Android 4.4
>   KitKat","tid":"126","time":"2013-09-06 20:51:32"},{"title":"Apple
>   Launches iPhone 5s and iPhone 5c","tid":"127","time":"2013-09-11
>   15:29:40"}]}

and this is the class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.nairation.library.JSONParser;
import com.nairation.library.UserFunctions;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Topic_page extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

    public static final String TOPIC_DURATION = "relative";
    public static final String TOPIC_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String TOPIC_PREVIEW = "Testing out";
    public static final String TOPIC_ID = null;
    public static final Object TOPIC_THUMB_URL = null;

    ListView list;
    TopicListAdapter adapter;
    UserFunctions userf;
    JSONParser jpa;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> topicList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.topic_page);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.topic_list);
        adapter = new TopicListAdapter(this, topicList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        try{
            new ServiceSync().execute("mash");
        }catch(Exception e){
            String message = e.getMessage();
        }

    }

    private class ServiceSync extends AsyncTask<String, JSONObject, JSONObject>{

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String uname = params[0];
            userf = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject jp = userf.getTopic(uname);
            return jp;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //super.onPostExecute(result);
            try {
                JSONArray obj = result.getJSONArray("data");

                for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject data = obj.getJSONObject(i);
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    String title = data.getString(TOPIC_TITLE);
                    String time = data.getString("time");
                    String tid = data.getString("tid");

                    map.put(TOPIC_TITLE, title);
                    map.put("Date", time);

                    topicList.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Problem with loading the feeds", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

So what could be the problem the JSON result is not being processed..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by not working you mean you cannot see the parsed data in the list , then for that you need to call **adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()** method whenever the underlying list is modified after setting the list to the adapter

Comment: Just tried putting it in the ServiceSync class and for some some reason the class can't see the adapter variable but it sees other variables form outside the class.

Comment: after your for loop when you have finished adding everything to topicList call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() and onDestroy() of activity cancel the asyncTask then onPostExecute() is not called

Answer (score 1):

Your error toast should be showing, i think this is your error:

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++)
```

should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < obj.length(); i++)
```

... use more descriptive variable names like

```
JSONArray feedArray = result.getJSONArray("data");
```

Comment: oh yeah...my bad..just fixed that and it stil displays the same error... i am thinking it's because of **adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()** in which i tried putting in the servicessync class..but it seems the class doesn't see the variable **adapter** but it sees all other external variables

Comment: it's true you should call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), however not calling it wouldn't result in an error. Try clean/rebuild your project, adapter should definately show up.

Comment: on another side note, your app will crash when onPostExecute and adapter.notifyDataSetChanged gets called after you left/closed the activity

Comment: how am i to fix this please..just give a me run through

Comment: see Ravis comment in the answer, that should fix it. (I'd put it in onStop() though this depends on the way you're planning navigation within your app)